# Set dependency properties in XAML when the base class is generic

Tags: c#, wpf, generics, xaml, .net-4.0

As per the title really, how can you set a dependency property in XAML when the base class is generic? When trying to do this I get a NullReferenceException, setting the property from code behind works fine. It also works when the base class is not generic.
I'm using .NET4

Here is some sample code to demonstrate:

**WindowBase.cs**

```
using System.Windows;

namespace GenericDependencyPropertyTest
{
    public class WindowBase<ViewModel> : Window
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Header", typeof(string), typeof(WindowBase<ViewModel>), new PropertyMetadata("No Header Name Assigned"));

        public string Header
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(HeaderProperty); }
            protected set { SetValue(HeaderProperty, value); }
        }
        protected virtual ViewModel Model { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<local:WindowBase x:Class="GenericDependencyPropertyTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GenericDependencyPropertyTest"
        x:TypeArguments="local:IMyViewModel"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Header="Test">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</local:WindowBase>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
namespace GenericDependencyPropertyTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : WindowBase<IMyViewModel>
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override IMyViewModel Model
        {
            get
            {
                return base.Model;
            }
            set
            {
                base.Model = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**IMyViewModel.cs**

```
namespace GenericDependencyPropertyTest
{
    public interface IMyViewModel
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "when the base class is generic"? Are you trying to say a custom control?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I mean a control (or window in this case) that inherits from a class that is generic, in my example above I'm passing an interface for the type of view model the window will have as MainWindow is inheriting from WindowBase.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My guess is that the problem lies with the owner type of the dependency property (typeof(WindowBase<ViewModel>). Each closed generic type will be a completely different runtime type so while the *compiler* is happy that the property exists the WPF runtime can't find it when it looks the property up against the (different) type in its internal storage.

As you found, the non-generic class works because the owner type and the runtime type are the same.

You can get the behaviour you want by pushing the DPs to a non-generic base but still derive your views from a generic class to get the strongly typed models

```
public class WindowBase : Window
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Header", typeof(string), typeof(WindowBase), new PropertyMetadata("No Header Name Assigned"));

    public string Header
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(HeaderProperty); }
        protected set { SetValue(HeaderProperty, value); }
    }
}

public class WindowBase<ViewModel> : WindowBase
{
    protected ViewModel Model { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: And here we are in 2018 and this helped me greatly. I'll approach all my classes using generics in this way in future.

I assume you've all moved on to bigger and better things!

Comment: @miriyo Good to hear the site's doing one of it's jobs as an historic knowledge base! Even if we've mostly moved on from WPF the scoping of statics in generic classes hasn't changed.