# Are generic UserControls and generic Dependency properties possible?

Tags: wpf, generics, dependency-properties, initializecomponent

I have an abstract generic class that defines a generic dependency property the type of which is to be defined by subclassing classes. This property is somehow not recognized as a dependency property so that I get an error message during runtime when binding to this property. Additionally during compilation time the constructor cannot call `InitializeComponent`. Why is that?

The generic abstract class `MyClass`:

```cs
abstract public class MyClass<T,U> : UserControl {
    protected MyClass() {
        InitializeComponent(); // Here is one error: Cannot be found
    }

    abstract protected U ListSource;

    private static void DPChanged
    (DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
        var myClassObj = (MyClass) d;
        myClassObj.DataContext = myClassObj.ListSource;
    }

    // Causes a binding error at runtime => DP (of the concrete subclass)
    // is not recognized as a dependency property 
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DPProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register(
        "DP", 
        typeof(T), 
        typeof(MyClass), 
        new PropertyMetadata(null, DPChanged));

    public T DP {
        get { return (T) GetValue(DPProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DPProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

The corresponding XAML:

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="Path.of.Namespace.MyClass"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ListView>
        <!-- Some stuff for the list view - used for all subclasses -->
    </ListView>
</UserControl>
```

A concrete subclass `MySubClass`:

```cs
public partial class MySubClass : MyClass<ClassWithAList, List<int>> {
    public MySubClass() {
        InitializeComponent(); // Another error: Cannot be found
    }

    protected List<int> ListSource {
        get { return new List<int>(); } // Just a dummy value

    }
}
```

The corresponding XAML:

```xml
<local:MySubClass xmlns:local="Path.of.Namespace.MySubClass" />
```

P.S. I am also not quite sure if the `partial` stuff is done correctly - R# suggests to remove these keywords.

Comment: Similar question here that might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629403/wpf-dependency-properties-set-in-xaml-when-base-class-is-generic

Comment: You inherit from ListView in code behind and have XAML that claims you inherit from UserControl, that cannot work...

Comment: @H.B. Ah sorry, the sample code was erroneous. I just updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are several things wrong with your code, but first, let me explain `partial` in this context:

`partial` is used to declare one class in separate files. As visual studio is creating a `MySubClass.g.cs` with a `partial class MySubClass` (btw. this is where the method `InitializeComponent` is declared)  from your `MySubClass.xaml` you'd have this class declaration twice and thus to get this to compile you will need the `partial` keyword.

Now to the rest: XAML and generics don't do well together, meaning: *not at all*. your 'corresponding XAML' is declaring a `MyClass`. But a `MyClass` without generic parameters doesn't exist. You could at this point change `x:Class="Path.of.Namespace.MyClass"` to `x:Class="Path.of.Namespace.MySubClass"`, that should work.

but now the next thing is: how do you want to access that dependecy property in xaml? it is a static member in a generic type, so you have to specify it like this in code: `MyClass<ClassWithAList, List<int>>.DPProperty`. The problem is again: you can't do that in xaml

to solve your problem it might be a good idea to tell us what you want to accomplish

Comment: Thank you for the good explanation. Actually what I tried to achieve was also possible without using generics. I just wanted to avoid defining Dependency Properties anew in each subclass - now I just stick to the more verbose solution that works as well (by not using generics).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem could be that you are writing typeof(MyClass), and should be `typeof(MyClass<T,U>)`.